# Adding an onload event for a gridview

Tags: jquery, html, gridview, html-table

I have one grid, here is html code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" id="grid1"
   rules="all">
        <tbody><tr>
 <th scope="col">Nr de ord</th>
 <th scope="col">StudentId</th>
 <th scope="col">Name LName</th>

 <th scope="col">
      <span id="mondayText">monday<br></span>
      <span id="monday">14.05.2012</span>
  </th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="thuesdayText">thuesday<br></span>
     <span id="thuesday">15.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="wednesdayText">wednesday<br></span>
     <span id="wednesday">16.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="thursdayText">thursday<br></span>
     <span id="thursday">17.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="fridayText">friday<br></span>
     <span id="friday">18.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="saturdayText">saturday<br></span>
     <span id="saturday">19.05.2012</span>
  </th>
   <th scope="col">
   <span id="M">Total1</span>
   </th>
  <th scope="col">
   <span id="N">Total2</span>
   </th>
               </tr><tr>
                <td>  1  </td>
                <td>110001</td>
                <td>Test1 Test1</td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_0" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl02$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a2222_0" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl02$a2222">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>

                          </td><td>
                          </td><td>
                          </td><td>
                          <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                          </td><td>
                           <span id="totalN"></span>
                          </td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td> 2   </td>
                <td>110002</td>
                <td>Test2 Test2</td>
                <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td><td>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_1" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl03$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>

                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                 </td><td>
                 <span id="totalN"></span>
                  </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                         3                  
                </td><td>110008</td><td>Test3 Test3</td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
<select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_2" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl04$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>
                         </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                 <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                </td><td>
                  <span id="totalN"></span>
                          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

With jQuery I'm calculating how many selects have index 1 and how many index 2, and it is calculated in this function on change event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             var collection = $('select.ddlJ');
             console.log(collection);
             for (var element in collection)
             $(element).change(function () {

    $('select.ddlJ').change(function (e) {
$(this).parent().parent().find('td:last').prev().find('span').html(
$(this).parent().parent().find('select.ddlJ').filter(function () {
return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'm'; }).length);

$(this).parent().parent().find('td:last span').html(
$(this).parent().parent().find('select.ddlJ').filter(function () {
return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'n'; }).length );

     });
   });
 });
```

But now I want to make the same calculations when the grid loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the contents of your `change` event and make it a separate function. Call that function at the bottom of your script.

Answer (score 2):

See this link.But it want to add dynamically on load the page.It is your Question ??

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ullasvk2000/Up5PY/1/][1]
```

Comment: My question is not held to add the row, but calculating how many Selects have some value selected for each row

Comment: I didnt understand.can you give me a example ?